# Можно ли восстановить проект, если есть только Exe Delphi

Tags: delphi

Случилась беда и случайно снял задачу в диспетчере вместе с открытым проектом по Delphi. Но остался скомпилированный exe файл, есть ли вариант восстановить из него проект ?

Comment: Сами формы можно код - считайте, что нет

Comment: Благодарю, уже переделал все :(

Comment: Если есть скомпилированный exe файл, то значит все файлы исходного код, из которых он был скомпилирован, сохранены на диске и восстанавливать нечего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настройках IDE Delphi ставим пункт "Автосохранение проекта перед запуском". В этом случае даже полностью зависший комп не страшен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, оказывается галочка стояла, я только что проверил, а куда среда сохраняет бекапы?

Comment: Проект хоть раз был сохранен? В таких случаях два варианта: yandex или постановка опыта. Делаем новый проект, ждем 10 минут, ищем файлы, которые поменялись в последние 10 минут (находим нужный нам бэкап). Вполне возможно, что просто автосохранение.